# Navigate to next group of features in QGIS form view of attribute table

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt

I'm using QGIS to visually interpret land dynamics over sample locations. Samples are spatially clustered and in many cases all samples of a cluster share the same dynamic and can be edited all at once.
I'd like to improve the navigation between clusters. Right now in the form view of the attribute table it is only possible to "navigate to next feature".

Would there be a way (e.g. simple custom UI) to "navigate to next feature group/cluster", using the `cluster_id` attribute value as grouping variable in the example dataset below?

For my use case it would be fine to pan to the first feature of the cluster and not recompute a new centroid given that features are spatially clustered.

See an example feature collection below:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3301" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cluster_id": 1, "class_id": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 584942.5, 6611242.5 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cluster_id": 1, "class_id": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 584942.5, 6611247.5 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cluster_id": 1, "class_id": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 584947.5, 6611247.5 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cluster_id": 1, "class_id": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 584947.5, 6611242.5 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cluster_id": 2, "class_id": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 585102.5, 6609342.5 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cluster_id": 2, "class_id": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 585102.5, 6609347.5 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cluster_id": 2, "class_id": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 585107.5, 6609342.5 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "cluster_id": 2, "class_id": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 585107.5, 6609347.5 ] } }
]
}
```